# FFT for speech signal with dividing frames in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, fft

I want to take FFT of speech signal first dividing the signal into 64 sample frames. I can do it by simply using "for" loops. However I'm sure there is a way to do in MATLAB in simpler manner. The thing I'm trying to do is simply: Taking FFT of

```
x1 = [ 1 2 3 4 6];
x2 = [ 2 3 1 3 5];
x3 = [ 3 3 4 5 6];
x  = [x1;x2;x3];
fft(x);
```

After I search, I realized that there is a parameter in FFT which is "dimension". However in my case, my matrix is 2015X64. How can I generate this new matrix with my original speech signal? When I want to use reshape, it seems that it is not proper to do this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your code takes the FFT of each column. Do you want the FFT of each row?

Comment: I realize my mistake:) I will take transpose of the matrix. Thank you for remark.

Comment: There is a built in function that can divide the audio signal for you and then take the FFT of each of the segment (i.e perform a Short time Fourier transform), it's called "spectrogram"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want

```
x = randn(1, 2015*64);      % // example data vector
x = reshape(x, 64, []).';   %'// separate x into rows of 64 columns
y = fft(x, [], 2);          % // take DFT of each row
```

Comment: Why did you use 2 in FFT?

Comment: That `2` indicates you want to apply the FFT to each row (that is, along the second dimension)